# Show that $f$ is real for all $z \neq 0$ (Application of Schwarz Reflection Principle)

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function, and $f (z) = f (\frac{1}{ z})$  for all $z \neq 0$. Suppose $f$ is real on $∂\Bbb D$ where $\Bbb D=D(0,1)$. Show that $f$ is real for all real $z \neq 0$.

The solution to this problem uses the Schwarz Reflection Principle.

The Schwarz Reflection Principle states:

Suppose that $f$ is an analytic function which is defined in the upper half-disk ${|z|^2<1,I[z]>0}$. Further suppose that $f$ extends to a continuous function on the real axis, and takes on real values on the real axis. Then $f$ can be extended to an analytic function on the whole disk by the formula $f(\overline{z})=\overline{f(z)}$

Using this for $D(0,1)$ we have $f(z)=\overline{f(\frac{1}{\overline z})}$

For $x$ real we get $f(x)=\overline{f(\frac{1}{x})}=\overline{f(x)}$ so $f(x)$ is real.

My question:

1. How does this concludes $f$ is real for all real $z \neq 0$?
2. Is there any other way to show this, i.e. without using the Schwarz Reflection Principle?

Comment: If a complex number equals is conjugate then it is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

First,

> Using this for $D(0,1)$ we have $f(z)=\overline{f(\frac{1}{z})}$

Here I suspect you've used the Reflection without verifying the requirements. Your statement of the Reflection Principle doesn't look right, either.

For this question I have two outlines for a solutions:

1. Using the Reflection Principle [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle): We map the unit disc via möbius transformation to the upper half plane. There we get a Relation for the transformed function. Together with $f(z)=f(1/z)$ it should result in something like $\overline{f(z)}=f(\overline{z})$.
2. We can calculate the power series at $z=0$. With the Cauchy integral formula
   $$f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz
   $$
   and $f(z)=f(\overline z)\in\mathbb{R}$ for $|z|=1$ we should get $f^{(n)}(0)\in\mathbb{R}$